# can't activate rack problem while install spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I install spree version 0.9.4 with `gem install spree` and run a set up command `spree mystore` and get this errors messages. Have anybody experienced this whether in spree or not ?

```
D:\Workspaces>spree mystore
C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:280:i
n `activate': can't activate rack (>= 1.0.1, runtime) for ["spree-0.9.4"], alrea
dy activated rack-1.0.0 for ["actionpack-2.3.5", "rails-2.3.5", "spree-0.9.4"] (
Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems.rb:296:in `activate'
        from C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems.rb:295:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems.rb:295:in `activate'
        from C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems.rb:68:in `gem'
    from C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/bin/spree:18
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found similar problems (with difference gem) all over the places and decided to solve it by install a new gem, and uninstall the old one

```
gem uninstall rack -v 1.0.0
```

then

```
gem install rack -v 1.0.1
```

hope this helps those who have similar problem.

p.s. see someone posting about freezing rails, but I didn't dig into it yet.

Comment: Thank you for helping this newb to Ruby out.  I was racking my head over this, no pun intended.  I ended up checking for a list of versions and found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears spree requires v1.0.1, whereas rack is now at version 1.1.0. Please install 1.0.1, the pain will go away.